# Order migrate to other magento

Tags: magento2, orders

How can I achieve to Migrate Orders from the Magento2 instance to another Magento2 instance? Which tables are responsible for managing orders?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems odd.To migrate orders, you need the products and you need the customers.
Which means you need all the category / invoice / refund

Basically you need everything from magento...you can't just retrieve orders separately.

Migrating the orders should be the last thing to do when migrating magento datas.

That being said.

What you can do is export your orders from Sales > Order > Export from your magento A website.

Then you need to create the code that will create the orders from the csv in your magento B. There are some modules already doing the job I would say it's easier to take one of these as for example : https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-use-magento-2-import-orders/

My approach would be to make a custom script creating the orders from the csv exported rather than raw database transfert that might create issues later.

You can always try to take all sales_order_* tables but i'm not sure about the result.